# add message to growl message componnent in primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, facescontext

hello i have a jsf page it contains a  message and a  i want add message only to the growl message and it does not work for me :

my java code is :

```
public class EtudeBean {



privaezte loneeg lotiezeffhssemgefntI12Etude;

public EtudeeBffeeezan() {
    eteude = new Eeezteeeude();
}

public Lotisseezement trouvezeerLoezezeztissement() {
    ez
    retureezn lotisszefdgemezeeeeezezntServiezezceImpl.trouvedfrLodfdtissement(getLfgfotiffdgssementIdEtude());

}

public void save(){
    etude.setDesignation(model.getDesignation());
    etude.setDescription(model.getDescription());
    etude.setCout(mezezodel.getCout());
    etude.setDeezezateezezezRealisation(model.getDateRealisation());
    eez
        etude.setLotissement(model.getLotis());
        etuezezezde.setIdEtude(model.getIdEtude());
        etudeSezeezezrviceImpl.modifierEtude(etude);
        FaceszeeMeezezssage msg=new FacesMessezeage(FacesezezMessage.SEeezVERITY_INFO,"Etude"+etude.getDesignation()+"modifiée avec succes","Mot de passe ancienne non valide: ");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage("growl",msg);

}
```

}

and the code of my jsf page :

```
<h:form id="form"  prependId="false">
<p:growl for="growl"  id="idgrowl"/> 
    <p:panel id="panel"
        header="New Etude for lotissment: #{etudeBedfsdsan.trouvedfssrLotissemdfent().nom}" >

        <p:messages id="msgs" />

        <h:panelGrdsfsdid columns="9" style="madffrgin-top:10px;">
            <h:outputLabel for="desigdfsnation" value="Designation: *"
                style="margin-right: 34px;" />
            <p:inputText id="designation" value="#{etudeBean.model.designation}"
                required="true" label="Designation">
                <f:validateLength minimum="2" />
            </p:inputText>
            <p:message for="designation" display="icon" />


            <h:outputLabel for="dateRealisation" value="Date Realisation: *    "
                style="margin-right: 34px;margin-left:34px;" />
            <p:calendar value="#{etufsddeBdsdsfean.model.dateRealisation}"
                pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />

        </h:panelGrid>

        <p:commandButton valudfse="Save" update="panel"
            action="#{etudeBean.save()}" />
    </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

have one any idea please help me and thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You have to add the growl to the update attribute of your commandButton, aswell.
Like this:

```
<p:growl id="idgrowl"/>
...
<p:commandButton value="Save" update="growl" action="#{etudeBean.save()}" />
```

And in your managed bean add the FacesMessage the following way:

```
FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,"Etude"+etude.getDesignation()+"modifiée avec succes","Mot de passe ancienne non valide: ");
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null,msg);
```

This should work.

Comment: LarsBauer

this does not work i obtain this error message:


    javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with expression "growl" referenced from "j_idt46".
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

please give me another solution becquse this one is not work

Comment: Your growl is located outside the panel in which the commandButton is nested. Just move the growl inside the panel, too. And tell me what happens then.

Comment: the same error javax.servlet.ServletException: Cannot find component with expression "growl" referenced from "j_idt46".
 javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)

Comment: the problem is not update="growl" but update="idgrowl"
now the message display into the tow component growl and p:messages i want display the message only in the growl commponent u undrestand me

Comment: The problem is that both components, growl and messages, are displaying FacesMessag sent from your managed bean. If you just want to update the growl remove "panel" from the update attribute of your commandButton: `<p:commandButton value="Save" update="growl" action="#{etudeBean.save}"/>`
Or do you also have to update the panel, too? Sorry, I didn't understand your question properly from the beginning.

Comment: probably you want to say <p:commandButton value="Save" update="idgrowl" action="#{etudeBean.save()}" /> check with attention update attribute which must have the id of the growl